# ReactJS DOM rendering lag

Tags: reactjs

I'm having issues with forcing the DOM to change in a child React element before changes occur in its parent React element.

The situation is this:

I have a Grid table with columns and rows, and then I have a Filter element which is a dropdown menu which will allow the user to filter the rows in the Grid by the desired value (i.e. if the user selects 'Active' in the Filter menu, then only rows with an 'Active' value will be shown).

The problem is that when I click an input in the Filter Menu, it seems that the component waits for the filtering to finish in the parent Grid before reflecting the DOM changes (the background changing in the Filter Menu).  This means that if I click on a filtering option, there's a lag before the CSS classes that I have applying to a checked option are applied

The code is something like this:

```
var Grid = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      rows: _.map(_.range(100000), function (i) {
          var state = (i % 2 == 0) ? 'active' : 'inactive';
          return {column1: state, column2: i};
      })
    };
  },

  _renderRows: function (rows) {
    return this.state.rows.map(function(row) {
      return <tr><td>{row.column1}</td><td>{row.column2}</td></tr>
    });
  },

  // For the sake of simplicity let's just say we can only filter on the
  // values for column1
  _onFilterChange: function(value) {
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.filter(function (row) { return row.column1 === value })
    });
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Filter
          handleFilterChange={this._onFilterChange}
        />
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {this._renderRows(this.state.rows)}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Filter = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      selected: {
        active: false
      }
    };
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.selected !== prevState.selected) {
      var value = (this.state.selected['active']) ? 'active' : 'inactive';
      this.props.handleFilterChange(value);
    }
  },

  _handleFilterChange: function (value, e) {
    optionSelected = {}
    optionSelected[value] = e.target.checked;
    var newSelected = React.addons.update(this.state.selected, {$merge: optionSelected});

    // This should cause a re-render of everything
    this.setState({
      selected: newSelected,
    });
  },

  render: function () {
    return (<ul>
      <li>
        <input
          id='active'
          type='checkbox'
          value='active'
          checked={this.state.selected['active']}
          onChange={this._handleFilterChange.bind(this, 'active')}
        />
        <label htmlFor='active'>Active</label>
      </li>
    </ul>);
  },
});
```

Is there any way to force the Filter Menu to render it's DOM / apply the CSS classes before the filtering function takes place in the parent Grid?

Comment: Putting the `this.props.handleFilterChange(value);` call in a `setTimeout` might do the trick (even if it is not pretty).

Comment: Using the setTimeout worked! But it is definitely not pretty... if there are no other answers I might end up using that..

Comment: I guess the issue is just that the browser doesn't have enough time to repaint. `setTimeout` moves the expensive filter operation into the next tick.

Comment: The weird thing is that I was calling the this.props.handleFilterChange in the componentDidUpdate which according to the React docs happens AFTER the DOM is flushed so I'm not completely clear why setTimeout works but putting it in componentDidUpdate doesn't

Comment: The DOM may be updated but not repainted yet. Not sure though.